# Preferred way of typecasting basic types in C++

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

Out of below 2 typecasting which one is preferred/better to use in a C++ code and why ?

```
unsigned char var = 10;
unsigned int value;
value = static_cast<unsigned int>(var);   //typecasting 1 
value = (unsigned int)var;                //typecasting 2
```

Comment: static_cast better. clear and safe.

Comment: You forgot the constructor like cast

Comment: In that particular case (`unsigned char` to `unsigned int`), you don't need a cast at all. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) for more details.